# Creating a Jukebox for class but my functionality is not working

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Jukebox and I feel like I have everything correct but when I got to play or pause I get errors in my console log that I don't understand. This is my code

```
//pull html buttons
var playBtn = document.getElementById("playBtn");
var pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pauseBtn");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");
var backBtn = document.getElementById("backBtn");
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
var index = 0
//make as JukeBox constructor 
function Jukebox(){
    this.jamz = []
}

//be able to add songs to the jukebox
Jukebox.prototype.addSong = function(songs){
    this.jamz.push(songs);
}

//test audio in console log
/*Jukebox.prototype.play = function(){
    var playSong = this.jamz;
    console.log(this.jamz)
}*/

//Be able to push songs into the jukebox. 
//first create a "new" jukebox
var jukebox = new Jukebox();

//use the previous prototype to add songs 

jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/Young M.A - OOOUUU.mp3"));
jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/J Balvin - Safari.mp3"));
jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/Marshmello x Ookay - Chasing Colors.mp3"));
jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/Bryson Tiller - Run Me Dry.mp3"));
jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/Midnight To Monaco - One In A 
Million.mp3"));


//give each button a method 

Jukebox.prototype.play = function(){
    this.jamz[index].play();
}

Jukebox.prototype.pause = function(){
    this.jamz[index].pause();
}

Jukebox.prototype.stop = function(){
    this.jamz[index].stop();
}
//figured out next button functionality through indexes. go back up top to 
variables and create and index variable
Jukebox.prototype.next= function(){
    this.jamz[index].pause(),
    index++;
    this.jamz[index].currentTime= 0,
    this.jamz[index].play;
    if (index ==this.jamz.length){
        this.index.currentTime = 0;
        this.jamz[index].play();
    }
};

//same functionality as "next except" if statement index will = 0

Jukebox.prototype.back = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  index--;
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  this.jamz[index].play();
  if (index === 0) {
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  }
};

//add event listeners to the the buttons I pulled earlier.
playBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 jukebox.play();
})

pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 jukebox.pause();
})

stopBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 jukebox.stop();
 })

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 jukebox.forward();
 })

backBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 jukebox.back();
 })
```

I'm looking for some advice on how to correct this issue. I have been staring at this for like an hour, maybe a second pair of eyes can help.

Comment: what the error in your console.log?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentTime' of undefined
    at Jukebox.back (script.js:67)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:98)
Jukebox.back @ script.js:67
(anonymous) @ script.js:98

Answer (score 0):

based on your error, you need to check if your object is undefined or not. it's a good practice to check if you are not sure your array has that index. seems like your index can be -1.

```js
Jukebox.prototype.back = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  index--;
  
  // put a break point around this line here so you can see the value of your index.
  // make sure you check your array agains undefined if you are not sure this index exist.
  if(typeof(this.jamz[index]) !== 'undefined'){
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
    if (index === 0) {
      this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
      this.jamz[index].play();
    }
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

what errors I found are `SyntaxError: unterminated string litera`

```
//figured out next button functionality through indexes. go back up top to 
variables and create and index variable // <= not coommented
Jukebox.prototype.next= function(){

jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/Midnight To Monaco - One In A 
Million.mp3")); // <= new line
```

and `jukebox.forward is not a function` it should be `jukebox.next()`

also there are no function `.stop()` you should pause and set current time to 0

```
Jukebox.prototype.stop = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  //this.jamz[index].stop();
}
```

```js
//pull html buttons
var playBtn = document.getElementById("playBtn");
var pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pauseBtn");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stopBtn");
var backBtn = document.getElementById("backBtn");
var nextBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
var index = 0;
//make as JukeBox constructor 
function Jukebox() {
  this.jamz = [];
}

//be able to add songs to the jukebox
Jukebox.prototype.addSong = function(songs) {
  this.jamz.push(songs);
};

//test audio in console log
/*Jukebox.prototype.play = function(){
    var playSong = this.jamz;
    console.log(this.jamz)
}*/

//Be able to push songs into the jukebox. 
//first create a "new" jukebox
var jukebox = new Jukebox();

//use the previous prototype to add songs 

jukebox.addSong(new Audio("https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/audio/rave_digger.webm"));
jukebox.addSong(new Audio("https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/audio/80s_vibe.webm"));
jukebox.addSong(new Audio("https://howlerjs.com/assets/howler.js/examples/player/audio/running_out.webm"));
//jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/Bryson Tiller - Run Me Dry.mp3"));
//jukebox.addSong(new Audio("audio/Midnight To Monaco - One In AMillion.mp3"));


//give each button a method 

Jukebox.prototype.play = function() {
  this.jamz[index].play();
};

Jukebox.prototype.pause = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
};

Jukebox.prototype.stop = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  //this.jamz[index].stop();
};

//figured out next button functionality through indexes. go back up top to 
//variables and create and index variable 
Jukebox.prototype.next = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
    index++;
    console.log(this.jamz[index]);
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  if(index == this.jamz.length) {
    this.index.currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  }
};

//same functionality as "next except" if statement index will = 0

Jukebox.prototype.back = function() {
  this.jamz[index].pause();
  index--;
  this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
  this.jamz[index].play();
  if(index === 0) {
    this.jamz[index].currentTime = 0;
    this.jamz[index].play();
  }
};

//add event listeners to the the buttons I pulled earlier.
playBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jukebox.play();
});

pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jukebox.pause();
});

stopBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jukebox.stop();
});

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jukebox.next();
});

backBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jukebox.back();
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="playBtn" value="playBtn">
<input type="button" id="pauseBtn" value="pauseBtn">
<input type="button" id="stopBtn" value="stopBtn">
<input type="button" id="backBtn" value="backBtn">
<input type="button" id="nextBtn" value="nextBtn">
```